# Azure Bicep and tenant scope (what-if vs create)

Tags: azure-bicep

I am deploying management group with Azure Bicep. While `create` works fine I am facing unexpected (at least for me it's unclear) issue with `what-if`. I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-to-management-group?tabs=azure-cli#management-group) approach. My "target" management group is not root tenant management group. The error message I am getting is:

`DeploymentWhatIfResourceError - The request to predict template deployment changes to scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/target-mg' has failed due to a resource error. See details for more information. AuthorizationFailed - The client '<<redacted>>' with object id '<<redacted>>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/read' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/test-name' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.`

Does `what-if` requires more permissions than create? I have the following template:

```
targetScope = 'managementGroup'
param name string = 'test-name'
param displayName string = 'test displayName'

resource managemagentGroup 'Microsoft.Management/managementGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: name
  scope: tenant()
  properties: {
    details: {
      parent: {
        id: managementGroup().id
      }
    }
    displayName: displayName
  }
}
```

and then run it like this:

```
# this fails with the error above.
az deployment mg what-if -f main.bicep -m target-mg -l westeurope

# this works fine
az deployment mg validate -f main.bicep -m target-mg -l westeurope

# this works fine
az deployment mg create -f main.bicep -m target-mg -l westeurope
```

Anyone run into the same issue?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this - what version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: Bicep CLI version 0.5.6 (5f2f88f0f0). Mac. User principal does not have "/" permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into a known issue where the ManagementGroup resource provider returns a 403 on a GET (instead of a 404) for a non-existent managementGroup.

What-If does a GET to look at the current state and receives the 403.  What-if assumes that 403 means what it says and that you don't have perms.  What-if should receive a 404 in this case.  To confirm this is what you're running into, if you go ahead and `create` the mg and then run `what-if` again it should succeed.

re: perms - if you have perms that will allow `validate` and `create` to succeed, then you have sufficient perms at scope - you don't need any perms at the tenant (i.e. "/") scope.

As for a workaround, you can give more perms to the principal to get around this but I haven't been able to nail down what minimal perms are...  I know if you're a tenant owner (i.e. perms at "/") this will work - which is why I couldn't reproduce it on my end - but that shouldn't be required and it equates to sudo/root permission, so not a great option.  The other option is just to skip what-if when you know the MG doesn't exist, that would require a separate step in the pipeline or somewhere outside the template to detect existence since you can't do that in the template.

That help?

Comment: Yes, for what-if it needs validate and read at the "/" scope even if you deploy to lowever level management groups. However the actual creation does not need this. In our case we will skip what-if. Thanks for the reply.